# Convert uint16_t array to char array - C++

Tags: c++

I'd like to convert

```
uint16_t status[8]; // change the values depend on the relay status: 0 or 1
```

to string containing a formatted representation of the eight status numbers seperated with commas e.g.
status[0] = 0, status [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTHI.png) = 0 ... so on, status[7] = 0 ---string--> "0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0"

When I use snprintf function it returns me "1073670272" in debug mqtt in node in node-red. [node-red debug message: 1073670272 value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTHI.png)

```
    // ...
uint16_t status[8];
char str[80];
long lastMsg = 0;
// ...
// loop ()
void loop() {
  mb.task();
  yield();
  
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

 long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 3000) {
    lastMsg = now;
  mb.readHreg(SLAVE_ID, 0x0001, status, 8, cbWrite); 
sprintf(str, "%u", status);
 client.publish("device1/relaysChannelStatus", str);
  }
}
```

When I print out status table before converting it with sprintf function it returns eight 0: [Serial port screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCgvQ.png)

```
for (int a=0; a<8; a++)
  {
    
  Serial.print(status[a]);
  }
```

PubSub functions requirements:

```
boolean publish(const char* topic, const char* payload);
boolean publish(const char* topic, const char* payload, boolean retained);
boolean publish(const char* topic, const uint8_t * payload, unsigned int plength);
boolean publish(const char* topic, const uint8_t * payload, unsigned int plength, boolean retained);
```

//
@Ayxan Haqverdili

```
void loop() {
 long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 3000) {
    lastMsg = now;
  mb.readHreg(SLAVE_ID, 0x0001, status, 8, cbWrite);   
    auto const sz = 8;
    uint16_t status[sz]; // uint16_t status[sz] = ...;
    char str[sz * 7];
    auto p = str;
    auto off = sprintf(p, "%d", status[0]);
    p+=off;
    for (int i = 1; i < sz; ++i){
      off = sprintf(p, ", %d", status[i]);
      p += off;
    }
     client.publish("device1/relaysChannelStatus", p);
  }
  }
```

and it returns an empty string: ""
[empty string debug ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQqgx.png)

@Barmak Shemirani

```
  mb.readHreg(SLAVE_ID, 0x0001, status, 8, cbWrite);
   Serial.println("BEFORE sprintf:");
  for (int a=0; a<8; a++)
  {

Serial.println(status[a]);
  }

    char statusString[20];
 sprintf(statusString, "%d", status);

 Serial.println("sprintf:");
   for (int a=0; a<8; a++)
  {

Serial.println(statusString[a]);
  }
Serial.println(statusString);
```

Serial port:
BEFORE sprintf:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
sprintf:
1
0
7
3
6
7
0
2

1073670208

Comment: Why did you tag c++?

Comment: Why did you tag c?

Comment: What's a "char table"?  Do you mean a `char` *array*?  What manner of conversion are you trying to achieve?  It looks like maybe you want a C string containing a formatted representation of the eight status numbers, but please be specific.

Comment: @JohnBollinger extacly, that's what I;d like to have I'm such a rookie. ;/

Comment: I didn't describe just one representation, but rather a whole category of them.  Again, *be specific*.  Decimal representation as opposed to hex, octal, or other? Fixed or variable width?  Space delimiters or something else?  If fixed width, then leading zeroes or not?  Very likely some of this would be answered already if you had shown what you have already tried, and explained why it's not producing the output you require.

Comment: in variable: status it returns 0 or 1 depends on relay status, so then variable width. I tried sprintf function and it returned different values as shown on the topic

Comment: Show how you did this with `sprintf` and what was the output. Is your desired output something like `"0xff 0x01 0xff 0x02"` or `"0xff01 0xff02"`?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani updated the topic:

Comment: Does this code compile? `for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) Serial.println(status[i], HEX);` or do it this way: `char buf[256] = { 0 }; for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "%04X ", status[i]); Serial.println(buf);` If there is nothing there then conversion `char` won't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you, tried it and it returns: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 when relays are off and 00001 ....  when is on so now i can send it, convert it in javasciript to single element of an array and make use of it. THANK YOU <3

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  auto const sz = 8;
  uint16_t status[sz] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
  
  char str[sz * 7];
  auto p = str;
  p += sprintf(p, "%d", status[0]);

  for (int i = 1; i < sz; ++i) {
    p += sprintf(p, ", %d", status[i]);
  }

  puts(str);
}
```

Comment: Copied it to loop() and get an error: error: expected primary-expression before '...' token
  357 |     uint16_t status[sz] = ...;

Comment: changed to uint16_t status[sz]; and it returns empty string: ""

Comment: @xxxbud obviously you need to initialize the `status` array yourself. Mine was an example assuming you already have the array

Comment: @xxxbud I updated the answer to include a complete example.